# Retrofit @URL does not seem to work with Response<T> as the return type in API

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, retrofit

### Code that fails

Api class

```
@GET
  fun getBlogPosts(@Url url: String): Response<List<BlogPostModel>>
```

Calling the api

```
homeApi.getBlogPosts("hidden-url")
```

### Code that runs

Api class

```
@GET
  fun getBlogPosts(@Url url: String): Call<List<BlogPostModel>>
```

Calling the api

```
homeApi.getBlogPosts("redacted-full-url").enqueue(callback)
```

Why doesn't @URL annotation works with Response?

#### Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<java.util.List<com.redacted.home.data.dataSources.remote.models.BlogPostModel>>
```

BlogPostModel class

```
data class BlogPostModel(
  @Json(name = "id") val id: Long = 0,
  @Json(name = "title") val title: RenderedModel = RenderedModel(),
  @Json(name = "content") val content: RenderedModel = RenderedModel(),
  @Json(name = "jetpack_featured_media_url") val featuredImageUrl: String = "",
  @Json(name = "date") val date: String = "",
  @Json(name = "status") val status: String = "",
  @Json(name = "type") val type: String = "",
  @Json(name = "excerpt") val excerpt: RenderedModel = RenderedModel(),
  @Json(name = "link") val link: String = ""
)

data class RenderedModel(
  @Json(name = "rendered") val rendered: String = ""
)
```

Comment: Its probably because `Response` is not meant to be used here. Instead of `Response<List<BlogPostModel>>` , try using `List<BlogPostModel>`. But then you can only make a synchronous request, if you want to make an asynchronous request you need to wrap the return type in a `Call`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling execute() instead of Call (2020 stop using callbacks.).

Then i chose the flow to flowOn a IO Dispatcher to overcome main thread issue.